# PNG files not showing in PHP download script

Tags: php, png

like always ... IE should be having some stupid rules to make coders work more ...

i am using a PHP class to server files from the server `(ex : http://site/downwload.php?id=5)` will download file that has id=5 ...

everything works just gr8 ... except PNG images on IE !!! works perfect on all other browsers ...

Any clue guys ?

Thank you .

Comment: What happens in IE? How does it "not work"?

Comment: it just displays an empty sized image (the red X mark)

Comment: Are the files all RGB? From memory, IE does not like CMYK colour profiles

Comment: Which IE? This question is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ,

IE doesn't like the `Content-Range` and `Content-Length` headers for png images ...

Comment: A Microsoft Knowledge base article. It's a link so click it :-)

Comment: hahaha ok am just too sleepy :p there are no proxy servers and this happens only with PNG images , u know , if u want to add all 'bugs' of internet explorer to Microsoft Knowledge base you may need trillions of terrabytes :p

Comment: Well, I'm not a fan of IE, no sane or competent person is, but to be fair that issue isn't really a IE bug ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you send any header that with content type? I can be a problem if you only send the data without the content type header.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('path/to/myimage.png');
```

Comment: Yes i am sending thew right headers , everything works gr8 on all other browsers ...